# What does "keep with" mean in this context?

Tags: prepositions, verbs, phrasal-verbs

I'm learning Html programming on one of the websites and during the course, there was a problem to solve which was phrased like this:

*"To* **keep with** *the same color theme you have already been using* (*black and brown), change the color for when the link is visited to black and use brown for when the link is actually clicked."*

...is this a **phrasal verb "keep with"** which means:

3. To conform to or remain in agreement with something. Used especially in the phrase "in keeping with something."
   *We want to ensure that the curriculum keeps with our religious beliefs.
   In keeping with the family's wishes, we're declining to make a comment on the case at this point in time.*(Farlex-Dictionary Of Idioms)

?

**or the verb "keep"** which means:

5. to continue or cause to continue: *keep the beat; keep in step.*(Collins Dictionary)

**and a preposition "with"?**

Comment: It might be a bit more informal, but ***stick** with [current approach]* is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=keep+with+this+approach%2Cstick+with+this+approach&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), and means exactly the same thing. And ***stick with*** gets [its own dictionary definition](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/stick-with) as a "phrasal verb", but you won't find any specific definitions for ***keep with***. Note that ***in keeping with** (consistent with)* is a special case "set phrase, frozen form".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example "keep with" is a phrasal verb and means "to remain with" or "to stay with" the colour scheme you are using and not change to another one.

Another synonymous phrase for your example would be "to stick with" the colour scheme.

Answer (score 2):

In that context, it's just the plain verb "keep" meaning "continue", "stay" or "remain" because that's all that is meant in that sentence. It just means *not change* to a different colour theme.

The phrasal verb "keep with" is used to mean follow or adhere to an established standard, a tradition, a long-standing pattern of behaviour, a philosophy, the wishes of someone important, etc. -- in short, it's something more significant than "black and brown".